# Javascript Off, How to disable page functionality

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a webpage which contains an ASP.net Wizard control that has some next and previous buttons. I also have a  tag which will display some text if someone goes to this webpage without javascript on the text will be displayed.

Even though i have this text displaying saying the webpage wont work if you dont have javascript enabled, people still dont turn on their javascript and continue thruogh the steps.

The Next and previous buttons still work which allows them to get to the end

Any suggestions on how i can disable the user from going through to the next step when javascript is off?

OR

Better alternative?

Comment: (What have you tried? Any code?)

Comment: Think about this for a second: could you change how the buttons work to exploit the fact that Javascript will not run when the user has disabled it?

Comment: Put some code please

Comment: I havent tried anything yet. Just looking at the different options i can use.

Answer (score 0):

A **simple one:** (not the best one)

- CSS `display:none;` on the main wrapper (here an advanced user could turn that `block`)
- Notice inside `<noscript>`
- JS apply `SomeWrapper.style.display = "block"` (Now you're sure they have JS)

---

**A better solution**
would be to build the entire FORM using JS. 
**No JS? No Form.**

BTW that latter is also a good technique to prevent bots from filling your pre-served HTML Forms - since it's now created dynamically